# Java: Writing a program that calculates midpoints based on randomly picking 2 out of 3 verticies

Tags: java

What I want to do is start with three points that make an equilateral triangle. My code should pick two of the three points at random, calculate a midpoint (m), and plot it. Then from the midpoint m it generated, the code will pick another one of the three original points at random and compute a new midpoint (m2). The last step should be repeated 10,000 times.
I'm just starting out with Java and am really lost. My biggest problem is that I don't know how to pick a point at random, and I also don't know how to go from taking the midpoint of two of the original points to taking the midpoint of the old midpoint and an original point. This is the code I have so far (please feel free to point out any mistakes I made in the code I have!):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Game
{
    static final int HEIGHT = 500;
    static final int WIDTH = 500;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Game");
        Board board = new Board(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        Point p1 = new Point(0,0);
        Point p2 = new Point(500, 0);
        Point p3 = new Point(0, 250);

        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(board);

        board.addPoint(p1);
        board.addPoint(p2);
        board.addPoint(p3);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}

class Board extends JPanel
{
    public Board(int h, int w)
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
    }

    public void addPoint(Point p)
    {

        points.add(p);
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);

        int i = 0;

        while (i < 10000)
            {
                board.add();
                i++;
            }

    }
}

class Point
{
    int x;
    int y;

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        x = this.x;
        y = this.y;
    }

    private static Point midPoint(Point p1, Point p2)
        {
            return new Point((p1.x + p2.x)/2, (p1.y + p2.y)/2);
        }

    public double getX()
    { 
        return x;
    }   

    public double getY()
    { 
        return y;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the problem. First, generate the 100000 points using your algorithm and add them to a list.

If you have a list of 3 points, and you want to pick two at random,
then `Collections.shuffle()` the list and pick the two first.

In the paint method, simply iterate the list and plot the points. No need to rebuild the list.

(Yes, you can do everything in the paint method and save some memory, but I think it's good for you to sort out your thoughts a little :-)

Edit:

Btw, the triangle in your example isn't equilateral.

Answer (score 0):

To pick one of three points, first pick a random number from 0 to 1 (using `Math.random()`). If the number is smaller than 1/3 take the first point, if it is between 1/3 and 2/3 take the second one, otherwise take the third point. Example:

```
 double r = Math.random();

 if ( r < 1.0/3) {
      // Chose first point
 } else if (r < 2.0/3) {
      // Choose second point
 } else {
      // Choose third point 
 }
```

Comment: @KarlP Yes you are correct. I misread the question. Sorry user2387999